# How to access pod IP from outside

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, calico

I'm rookie to k8s.

I know the pod IP is set in range by `--cluster-cidr`. eg. `10.244.0.0/18`

My question is how to access the pod IP from outside the k8s cluster.

I heard of 2 ways to do that:

- 1. Make **Docker** bridge use a self defined Linux bridge, some tricks in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, then add route records at the router device by `ip route add 10.244.0.0/18 via {k8sNodeIp}`(or something like that, I dont know details).
- 2. Similar to the upper one, but they seems accomplish that without the "bridge tricks", just add some route records(tell me if I'm wrong).

These solutions are from two different teams.

I dont know if the k8s network plugin got involved, the first one uses `flannel` and the last one uses `calico`.

Any docs about that?

Comment: why not use Kubernetes Service of type NodePort?

Comment: The recommended way of accessing a pod is via services. Using IP is not easy to mange and scale. If you don't need to consider scalability maybe you don't need k8s.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu These solutions are not for production usage, just for some debug or develop conveniences.I cant find any docs about that.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You can use `kubectl port-forward` to talk directly to containers in Pods ***for the purposes of debugging / development***.

E.g. `kubectl port-forward mypod 5000:6000`

See docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

### More Info

This command will set up a proxy on your workstation so that you can run, for example:

```
curl localhost:5000/api/v1/status
```

This request will be forwarded to the API Server, which will then forward your request to the Pod you specify in the `port-forward` command.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want.I setup a **OpenVPN** server on one of the k8s edge nodes, then with a vpn client on my windows desktop to connect to the k8s network.It works for me.

Comment: Right yep, I answered just this `My question is how to access the pod IP from outside the k8s cluster.`