# Access pod application by pod IP outside Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

First, I did some research on google.
Also, I have checked this article: [How to access pod IP from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008870/how-to-access-pod-ip-from-outside)

But I still have a question.

My Setup:

- My Windows PC (ip/128GB)

  - 14 ubuntu servers running on Hyper-V

I have 2 "environments": Dev and Staging.

Dev - I have 1 machine with K8S (Master, but I'm running my pods on it)

STG - 3 machines with k9s - cluster

Now I'm running my simple web app on a dev k8s machine.
I see in the k8s dashboard my pod, with IP: 10.XX.XX.XX.
If I RDP into the machine and open the browser - I can open my web app - everything works well. Nice!

Now, what I want is - to be able to open a browser on my Windows (HOST) machine, put in the URL IP of a pod from DEV (or STG) k8s and to see my web app.

In the article above I see that TA has installed OpenVPN and this solved his issue.

If I do it, can it help me?
(I don`t want to use a proxy, port forward, etc.)

I'm a little bit confused because my VM's using switch and the VM is in the same network with My host, so I'm not sure if I need VPN.

If not - how I can access to pod app by pod Ip from My host?

Thanks

Updated:

Maybe something like Fabio + Consul, or  Ocelot/Kong Gateway can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Nodeport or Loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) service for your pod and access your pod from the host machine by "VM ip:port".

Comment: Yes, I know about those options but - My question is how to access pod by POD IP and not by VM IP